# In Nltk, while cleaning text in each row, how to combine the alternate words into the same row? currently it appears as different items

Tags: nltk

[image]

Ideally the 1st, 2nd and 4th row should be combined into one row. This output is after completing Stemming, Lemmatizing, BeautifulSoup and using regular expression of retaining only alphabets, etc...

Please help me if there is any method to combine this different rows which actually means the same - currently it appears different as the words are interchanged.

Thanks & Regards
Madhan

Comment: It's very hard to even define what "meaning the same" means. And it's very hard to implement this, in general. In your case, you might be best off using some heuristics, like removing the word "service" and sorting the remaining words alphabetically.

Comment: It would have been better (and easy enough) to type in your sample data; images of text are not as easy to read or discover, and as you see new users are not allowed to show them.

Comment: If you can describe the criterion for when to merge the lines _without reference to meaning_, we can tell you how to do it. The first and last line have three words in common, so why not merge them? Also, what do you want the "combined" row to look like when each contributor has one or more unique words?

Comment: Short answer: "NLTK can help you minimally to do some NLP, and how you apply NLP to solve a task is up to the imagination". Shorter answer: try `gensim` instead, or `spacy` or better still some SOTA NN/DL/ML methods with `xgboost` or `lightgbm` or `tensorflow` or `mxnet` or `paddle-paddle` or any other NN/DL/ML libraries =)